# Check for line on bingo program with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this problem of bingo, where I have to check for bingo, line, or nothing, for a given input, where I get the 3 X 3 bingo card, and next 15 numbers extracted. I've wrote some code and I pass the tests for bingo and nothing, but not for line and I don't know why because I think my logic is good.

Here is the input:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11
12
13
14
15
16

I should have the result "line" but I get "nothing" instead. I think that my problem is on CheckLine method and I think this happens because somehow I don't pass correct parameters or maybe I have/or don't have to use ref keyword on some parameters. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Here is my code:

```
static void Main()
{
    const int numberOfRows = 3;
    const int numberOfColumnns = 3;
    const int numbersExtracted = 15;
    int[,] bingoCard = ReadBingoCard(numberOfRows, numberOfColumnns);
    int[] numbers = ReadNumbersExtracted(numbersExtracted);
    PrintResult(bingoCard, numbers);
}

static int[,] ReadBingoCard(int rowsNumber, int columnNumber)
{
    int[,] card = new int[rowsNumber, columnNumber];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
    {
        string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        for (int j = 0; j < columnNumber; j++)
        {
            card[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(array[j]);
        }
    }

    return card;
}

static int[] ReadNumbersExtracted(int numbersExtracted)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersExtracted];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersExtracted; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    return numbers;
}

static void CheckLine(int[,] bingoCard, int nr, int nr2, int[] numbersExtracted, 
    ref int counter, int nr3, ref bool isTrue)
{
    const int rowEnd = 2;
    bool isLine = counter == nr3 && nr2 == rowEnd;

    for (int k = 0; k < numbersExtracted.Length; k++)
    {
        if (bingoCard[nr, nr2] == numbersExtracted[k])
        {
            counter++;

            if (isLine)
            {
                isTrue = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void CheckBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int nr, int nr2, int[] numbersExtracted, 
    ref int counter, int nr3, ref bool isTrue)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < numbersExtracted.Length; k++)
    {
        if (bingoCard[nr, nr2] == numbersExtracted[k])
        {
            counter++;

            if (counter == nr3)
            {
                isTrue = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
{
    const int length = 3;
    int count = 0;
    bool isLine = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < bingoCard.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bingoCard.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            CheckLine(bingoCard, i, j, numbersExtracted, ref count, length, ref isLine);
        }
    }

    return isLine;
}

static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
{
    const int length = 9;
    int count = 0;
    bool isBingo = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < bingoCard.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bingoCard.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            CheckBingo(bingoCard, i, j, numbersExtracted, ref count, length, ref isBingo);
        }
    }

    return isBingo;
}

static void PrintResult(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
{
    if (CheckForBingo(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bingo");
    }
    else if (CheckForLine(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("linie");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("nimic");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through with a debugger?  There is too much code here and no effort to narrow down the problem.  It should be trivial for you to do a bit of debug work here first.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm new with programming, and I found it really confusing using debugging with functions calling...they try to teach us to use functions and I get so dizzy with debugging like this. Is not like I didn't try it, is just that I found it really hard to watch what happens

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with this bingo software.  The next thing you need to learn is [how to use the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).  You must learn this skill if you intend to develop software - there is no way to succeed otherwise.

Comment: From what I could understand from debbguing, I think it has something to do with ref keyword on method CheckLine...but I already tried that with some parameters and I get same result.

Comment: Why do you think that?  Are you sure all of your methods work properly?  Consider writing a test for each of your methods to make sure they behave the way you think.  Is the problem in `ReadBingoCard`, or perhaps in `CheckBingo`?  Who knows?  If you didn't test those methods then you don't know if you should expect them to work.  So test them - one at a time, give them inputs and check that they do the correct thing.

Comment: I dont know how to write tests, I told you I'm new to programming. CheckBingo method and all the rest works as they should. CheckLine method is the problem...I started the code in classic way with no methods and my logic works. But I have to use Analizators for write clean code, and the analizators forced me to get rid of nested IF and I had to break down in other smallers methods and I totally agree with this. But now this is what I've been able to do, and is not working anymore...And that's why I think it has something to do with how parameters are passed.

Comment: If you know that `CheckLine` is the problem then you should now [edit] the question to include that information and the debugging details that led you to that conclusion.  What result does it give you and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Overall, I think the code analyzers did not help you out.  This code is not improved from one big method - it's broken into small parts, but you still pass the global state through all of the arguments, which is completely counterproductive and just makes the code more difficult to read, follow and maintain.  The methods all still act in cooperation and implicitly expect that the other methods know what each other are doing, and they all still share the same master variables - only now hidden through arguments. I think if you have a working version I would go back and start the redesign again.

Comment: I totally agree with you but as I told you I'm new to programming. Also this is a Intro lesson, and now I'm learning methods and analyzers. So at my level this is best I could come with. Is not like I don't agree with you but this is my experience until now:). I've been coding since 1.5 months:)

Comment: Bingo is when from the 15 numbers extracted, 9 of them match the 9 of the bingo card. Line is when from the 15 numbers extracted, 3 o them match 1 line of the matrix (bingo card line). It doesn't matter the order the numbers extracted get out. They just have to match with what's on the card

Comment: Only horizontal.

Comment: I think the problem is the use of `ref` - you're passing program state around and it will get messy. Each method should perform a discreet operation on some input and return a value (typically).

Comment: Yeah this is what I was telling also in my question...but if I don't use ref on counter parameter on CheckLine method, the analyzers force me to change my variable count in my CheckForLine method into constant, and I don't want that because that increment on count is what makes my logic working. I mean I don't know how to do it otherwise

Comment: @CatalinUrcan My advice would be to forget about analyzers until you learn what you're doing.  Those tools are intended for people who understand what the tool is suggesting and what the reasons are for the suggestion.  In this case, I don't think that really applies, so you're basically treating the analyzer like a god or a mentor that will give you answers that you should follow like commandments.  This is wrong and it will lead you into trouble.  I would take some time to study introductory software development material to get a better handle on the basics first.  Rushing doesn't help.

Comment: I totally agree with you but they don't accept my solutions without analyzers:((. Even now that @Rufus L help me understand I still have to do it according to the analyzers and I get the same result...because of the parameters and ref X(....it's really annoying.

Comment: What is an analyzer?

Comment: Its a NuGetPackage...I have to do this problem with this 4 packages: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, Rosylnator.Analyzers, SonarAnalyzer.CSharp, StyleCop.Analyzers. Do you have skype? I think it could be more easier if I show u my screen

Comment: And the thing is @J that I've made the algorithm before without those analyzers and it works. But now I have to reformat code like a pro and keep the algorithm working...and from here all my problems

Comment: I've made it. Thank you for your help @RufusL

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem here is that you're passing program state around to the methods using `ref` arguments. This can lead to problems because the state is now shared between methods and can easily get out of sync if we're not careful.

Instead we should define methods that take in some information, do some calculation, and return a result. It makes tracking down problems much easier this way.

For example, to determine if there is a "Bingo", we need to check if all items in the `bingoCard` array are also in the `numbers` array. This can be done fairly easily with a nested loop, where we:

1. Loop over each `row` in the `bingoCard` array
2. For each row we look at each `column` value.
3. Then we loop over the `numbers` array to see if there's a match for the value.

   - If there's a match, then we can increment a counter.
   - If, when we're done, the counter equals the number of items in the `bingoCard` array, then we return `true`
   - Otherwise return `false`

For example:

```
static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
{
    int numMatchesFound = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
            {
                if (bingoCard[row, col] == numbers[numIndex])
                {
                    // Match found! Increment our counter and break from this loop
                    numMatchesFound++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If the number of matches equals the number of items in the card, return 'true'
    return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
}
```

Similarly, to check for a "line" we examine each row, and for each row we look at the column value. Then we loop through the `numbers` array to see if there's a match. If there is, then we increment a counter. If, at the end of the columns loop, our counter matches the total number of columns, then we have a "line" and return `true`. Otherwise, if we get to the end of the loops, then we return `false`:

```
static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        // For a 'line', we only need to match all columns in a row, 
        // so create a counter to track that here
        int colMatchesInRow = 0;

        for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
            {
                if (bingoCard[row, col] == numbers[numIndex])
                {
                    // Match found! Increment our counter and break from this loop
                    colMatchesInRow++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // If our counter equals the number of columns, return 'true'
        if (colMatchesInRow == bingoCard.GetLength(1)) return true;
    }

    // If we get this far, we never found a 'line', so return 'false'
    return false;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.